# Need help in reducing array of object into a single sum

Tags: shell, jq

In shell script, I have below array of object:

```
response={
        "product": "BIG MAC",
        "objects": [
                        {
                            "qty": 10,
                            "size": 32
                        },
                        {
                            "qty": 20,
                            "size": 53
                        },
                        {
                            "qty": 10,
                            "size": 54
                        }
        ]
    }
```

I am writing a jq function to get total quantity.

```
data=$( echo $response | jq '.objects[] | .qty ' )
```

This gives me one line of quantities, like

```
10 20 10
```

How do I sum these to get value:

```
40
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array and pipe that through `add`:

```
jq '[.objects[] | .qty] | add'
```

Using `map` might make this simpler, as you don't have to "index" `.objects` first:

```
jq '.objects | map(.qty) | add'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a stream-oriented addition function yields a solution that avoids the inefficiencies of constructing an array:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+$x);

sigma(.objects[] | .qty)
```

`sigma` as defined here is a good candidate for your "standard library" of jq functions.